# How to log an error in the console if one of the callables of the executor service encounter an error

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a program which uses `executorService` to which I am passing `callables`.

Each of which is an object of one class which implements `java.util.concurrent.Callable`.

Then the `executorService` is invoked. A `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown in the middle of one of the callables in the `call()` method.

However it is not terminating nor getting logged on the console. Therefore there is no way to know if the program has worked correctly or not. Kindly suggest any way by which I can understand the same.

Comment: don't you print the exception if raises?

Comment: Do you want to `print` the error message on the console or log it into an external file?

Comment: @nafas : It is not an error not an exception.

Comment: @user3337714: Anything would do just want to detect it. It is getting passed undetected. I even tried throwing it manually in the call method.

Comment: @KaustubhSV "It is not an error not an exception." so is it an error or exception?

Comment: @nafas `NoClassDefFoundError` is an error, as its name suggests.

Comment: @KaustubhSV Did you try using `try catch`. Wherever the error is thrown, `catch` the same and print.

Comment: @biziclop read the 3rd comment mate

Comment: @KaustubhSV Also if this is an error, it is recommended not to catch the same. I would recommend implement an exception and use the same.

Comment: Yes.. sorry for the typo there... It is an error! :)

Comment: You can extend  `ThreadPoolExecutor` and override the `afterExecute()` method but that isn't much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some one had already posted answer to this question, but when I came to mark it as answer after verifying, the post was unfortunately deleted. I am just retyping the answer.

The Futures which are returned by the **ExecutorService** after calling the invoke method contain all the Future objects of the thread. If anything goes wrong in any of the threads, an `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException` is thrown. Which can be detected in the parent thread which owns the executorService when we do `get()` on the Future. Then `e.getCause()` after catching it will get us the actual object which caused an error/exception.

Answer (score 2):

A [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) throws an Exception, which is not the superclass of [NoClassDefFoundError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html). Within your Callable, catch Error (or even Throwable) and wrap it with an Exception:

```
V call() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
       return this.doSomething();
    } catch (Error e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new Exception(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I was able to catch the error. But as we already know it is not advised. But when the parent thread which owns the executorService comes into picture, it is not able to catch this thrown exception.

Answer (score 2):

In order to print the error to the console, you can create a [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHander](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html). Passing it into the [Thread#setDefaultUncaughtThreadExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) will cause the handler to be invoked when the error is thrown.